# Closing a QDialog launched from a mouseReleaseEvent RightClick causes a blank context menu to appear

Tags: qt, contextmenu, mouseevent, qgraphicsitem, qdialog

This has happened for every QDialog I pop that fires from either a mouseReleaseEvent on a QGraphicsItem or from a QContextMenu. I don't see what the issue is - the code is pretty simple..

```
...
void MyQGfxItem::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(event->button() == Qt::RightButton)
    {
        MyDialog someDlg;
        if(someDlg.exec())
        {

        }
    }
}
...
```

As soon as the dialog is closed, either through OK or Cancel, an empty context menu appears where the event was triggered:

[image]

The blank item seems to control if my QDockWidget is hidden or visible.. Any idea what is going on? Numerous Google searches has left me stuck.

Edit - it looks like this only occurs if the Right mouse button is used..

Comment: Have you tried accepting the event? E.g., in your mouseReleaseEvent, you would call event->accept().

Comment: Why aren't you using a custom context menu instead of using raw mouse events ?

Comment: The issue is I don't even want a context menu showing up. The right clicks are for some reason showing an "empty" context menu that controls a QDockWidget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha! Got it. It looks like the QMainWindow grabs Right-click events after everything is finished. Calling this->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::NoContextMenu) in the QMainWindow suppressed it.

Comment: It's a bit of a hack, though. What if you end up needing context menus in the main window? It's probably worth figuring out why the event is propagating like that, and fixing it, rather than continuing to let it propagate, but just completely blocking off context menus at the end.

Comment: The thing is, no where in my code have I defined a context menu with an empty item that controls my QDockWidget - I have no idea where it would be coming from.

Comment: @David: When you add a QDockWidget to a QMainWindow, an item matching the name of your QDockWidget is added to the QMainWindow context menu which toggles its visibility. It's blank because you didn't pass a name to the constructor of the QDockWidget.

Comment: @Bill Oh wow, that makes perfect sense now. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs for QEvent, you should accept() events you do not want propagated to the parent widget. So somewhere in your mouseReleaseEvent, you should just add

```
event->setAccepted(true);
```

or

```
event->accept();
```

Note that you might also need to put this code in your mousePressEvent, too.

Comment: Tried it - that context menu still fires